# Data Processing Before Rendering in React Native Functional Component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a React Native functional component.

I'm using useEffect to fetch some data from AsycStorage and set it to local state. However, before rendering, I want to do some processing/calculations on this data before I can render it on screen. Where should I be doing this calculation?

My screen looks as follows:

```
const BasicScreen = ({ data, getPosts }) => {

  const [myItems, setItems] = useState([]);

  const checkForItems = () => {
    var storageItems = AsyncStorage.getItem("MyItems").then((item) => {
      if (item) {
        return JSON.parse(item);
      }
    });
    setItems(storageItems);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getItems() {
      await checkForItems(); // calling function to get data from storage
    }
    getItems(); // Local Storage
    getPosts(); // Store action
  }, []);

    return (
      <View>
        <>
          <Text>{JSON.stringify(processedItemsA)}</Text>
          <Text>{JSON.stringify(processedItemsB)}</Text>
        </>
      </View>
    );
}

export default BasicScreen;
```

As you can see, I check for items in AsyncStorage and set that data to local state myItems.

I want to do some mathematical calculations and some conditional logic, for example, separate the data of myItems into two separate categories, and then render that on screen. Something like `processedItemsA` and `processedItemsB`. Where should I be doing this processing of data?

```
processedItemsA = myItems => {
// Some logic
}

processedItemsB = myItems => {
// Some logic
}
```

I'm not sure about where this logic should go.

Note that this processing is required because apart from storage, I also get some data from redux store, and then process it along with that data.

Comment: What you could do is create another ```setState()``` where you read in the data from ```myItems``` then process it however you wish to with those functions then set it using the newer ```setState()```.

Comment: But I can't use setState in functional components, or can I?

Comment: You are doing it in the function ```checkForItems()```.

Comment: `useMemo` is a good choice here. It runs with the render, whereas `useEffect` runs after the render.

Comment: Oh you mean setItems? Ok. I was think what if I create another useEffect function and from there call another function to do this processing. Will that be okay?

Comment: use async await in case of getting data from AsyncStorage rather than the callback. 
var storageItems = await AsyncStorage.getItem("MyItems"); Then you will have all the data in storageItems and process it accordingly in the same function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way you can achieve this

```
const [processedItemsA, setProcessedItemsA] = useState({});
const [processedItemsB, setProcessedItemsB] = useState({});

doProcessedItemsA = myItems => {
  ...
  setProcessedItemsA({...data}); // set data after process Item A
}

doProcessedItemsB = myItems => {
  ...
  setProcessedItemsB({...data}); // set data after process Item B
}

const checkForItems = () => {
    var storageItems = AsyncStorage.getItem("MyItems").then((item) => {
      if (item) {
        const parsedItem = JSON.parse(item);
    doProcessedItemsA(parsedItem);
    doProcessedItemsB(parsedItem);
      }
    });
    // setItems(storageItems); <-- No need to set here -->
};
```

Comment: I'm implementing it in this way. So, the function checkForItems can be called from useEffect?

Comment: Yes exactly will call from there

Comment: Can I restructure this with async await as suggested by someone above? I tried doing it but something goes wrong and the data remains unset.

Comment: Yes, try with async